# The term 'Select-String' is not recognized

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to get only the PID by running this python script.

**My current error:**

1. Select string is not recognized as an internal or external command
2. To deal with this error, I thought that I needed to escape | by adding ^ --> But apparently it doesn't work
3. I added in some \ to escape ", hopefully it's correct?

   ```
   cmd = "netstat -ano | findstr " + str(o)
   print (cmd)
   cmd += " | Select-String \"TCP\s+(.+)\:(.+)\s+(.+)\:(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\" | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_.matches[0].Groups[6].value }"
   print (cmd)

   pid = run_command(cmd)
   ```

The run_command method does this:

```
def  run_command(cmd_array,os_name='posix'):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_array,shell=True,cwd=os.getcwd())
    output,err = p.communicate()
    print('output=%s'%output)
    print('err=%s'%err)
return output
```

**Expected Result**

When I run solely the command in command prompt, it gives me the PID --> which is 7556 in this case. 
Not too sure why it is not working for the script but working in command prompt by itself.

[image]

Comment: What `shell=True` refers to on Windows is `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell, so you cannot run PowerShell commands directly this way.

Comment: hi @mklement0, i see. In that case, i will have to add powershell -Command in front of netstat - ano? Quite new to this so i am referencing to other stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True`, invoke `powershell.exe`, with an array of arguments set to `-noprofile`, `-c`, and the command line to be executed by PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is specific to windows OS

**Answer to my own question**

1. With help from the comments, i did not use my run_command method since it was using shell = True.

> shell = True refers to cmd.exe on Windows, not powershell. 
>   The commands i have written are powershell commands.

2. Directly use subprocess.call to run powershell commands

Python scripts

```
cmd = "netstat -ano | findstr 8080"
cmd += " | Select-String \"TCP\s+(.+)\:(.+)\s+(.+)\:(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\" | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_.matches[0].Groups[6].value }"

subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", cmd])
#this does the job but the code will print extra zeros along with PID. It was not what i was looking for.
```

Result:

> 6492  (Prints out the PID Along with some additional zeros)

**What worked for me - For those who are trying to get only PID and kill port using PID in python script**

```
cmd = "for /f \"tokens=5\" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find \":8080"
cmd += "\" ^| find \"LISTENING\"\') do taskkill /f /pid %a"

#I added in some \ to escape the "

run_command(cmd)
```

Result:

> SUCCESS: The process with PID 2072 has been terminated